Прописная или строчная буква ставится после апострофа в именах собственных?
Скажите, пожалуйста, если после первой буквы в имени стоит апостроф, нужно ли следующую за ней букву также писать с прописной? Например: Н'каро/Н'Каро, Г'гуэдос/Г'Гуэдос.
ДОПОЛНЕНО (04.10.2024)
"Грамота.ру" ответила так (см. вопрос № 317570):

Рекомендаций по орфографическому оформлению такого рода имен в
справочной литературе нет. Полный академический справочник «Правила
русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина рассматривает
только такие случаи, когда апостроф используется при передаче
иностранных фамилий с начальными буквами Д и О, в этих случаях
следующая за апострофом буква — прописная. При этом романские
служебные слова д' и л' перед именем пишутся по общему правилу
строчными (Жанна д'Арк, аббат де л'Эпе), а начальная часть О' —
прописной (О'Коннор, О'Нил).
Если с такими вводными данными подходить к ответу на Ваш вопрос, то
выбирать следует между написаниями н'Каро и Н'Каро, г'Гуэдос и
Г'Гуэдос. Представляется, что на написание по-русски может повлиять и
написание в языке-источнике. Если же язык-источник не дает ответа на
данный вопрос, руководствуемся общим правилом: иностранные служебные
слова пишутся со строчной буквы.


• Вот что имеется в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:

§ 115. Апостроф
Знак апостроф — надстрочная запятая — имеет в русском письме ограниченное применение. Он используется при передаче иностранных фамилий с начальными буквами Д и О; при этом воспроизводится написание языка источника, напр.: Д’Аламбер (D’Alembert), Д’Аннунцио, д’Артаньян, Жанна д’Арк, д’Обинье, д’Эрвильи, О’Брайен, О’Коннор, О’Нил (но: О. Генри); то же в географических наименованиях типа Кот д’Ивуар (государство), Кот д’Ор (департамент во Франции).
Примечание. В словах, производных от слов с апострофом, этот знак не пишется, напр.: дартаньяновский.

• Мне не встречались с апострофом имена или названия, начинающиеся с Н или Г.
• Еще примеры:
Ронни О'Салливан (англ. Ronald Antonio O'Sullivan, снукерист),
шевалье д'Эон (Шарль-Женевьев-Луи-Огюст-Андре-Тимоте д’Эон де Бомон),
О'Хара (англ. O'Hara),
Генрих Луи д’Арре (нем. Heinrich Louis d'Arrest, астроном),
Гвидо д'Ареццо (итал. Guido d'Arezzo),
Л'Алькерия-д'Аснар (кат. L'Alqueria d'Asnar, муниципалитет в Испании),
Чель д’Оро (итал. Basilica di San Pietro in Ciel d’Oro),
Л'Умо (фр. L’ Houmeau, коммуна),
Ка'д'Оро (итал. Ca' d'Oro, Ca — cокращение от Casa (дом), «Золотой дом» — дворец в Венеции; встречается написание Ка-д’Оро).
● Во всех случаях, кроме последнего, после апострофа идет прописная буква.

Римма: "Во всех случаях, кроме последнего, после апострофа идет прописная буква". Не вижу строчной в последнем... :)

Вечер добрый, Саша! Ты, наверно, не обратил внимания на то, что в последнем примере два апострофа. Вот после первого и стоит строчная буква. Встречается еще такое написание, с пробелом — Ка' д'Оро (или палаццо Санта-София).

Добрый, Римма! Обратил. Но хотел увидеть маленькую в "основном" имени, а не в этих ихних приставках (они как раз, как я вижу, могут писаться и так и так, в силу традиций наверное).

Спасибо. Ну... Можно, конечно, изничтожить "кроме последнего". Но тогда дотошный пользователь может "прицепиться" к строчной "д". Можно, кстати, и двухопострофный пример убрать. Но — красивое же словечко, правда? Выцарапала. Жалко...

Обсудили – пусть останется как есть. Красивое :)
